Calculating Present Value
I need to calculate the present value of £$1000$ due in $10$ years' time if the effective rate of interest is $5$% per annum.
I solved this by doing $1000 \cdot e^{-\int_{0}^{10}0.05 \cdot dt} = £606.53$. But my notes say the answer is £$613.91$.
What have I done wrong?

See my comment, following the answer of true blue anil.

The effective rate has been given per annum
So you should simply do $1000\times(1.05)^{-10}$
You have used instead a continuous compounding formula which will necessarily give you a lower present value

+1 : to your answer.  Certainly, to a mathematician, the phrase "effective rate of interest" is unambiguous, which implies that your answer is dead-on accurate.  However, banking executives play fast and loose with language, and might well use the same phrase to represent compounding continuously at a rate of 5%, which implies that at the end of one year, $~1$$ has grown to something greater than $~1.05$.$  So, the original poster (perhaps inadvertently, given that this is a math problem) has a point.

@user2661923: Bankers might use effective rate ambiguously, but effective rate per annum should be totally unambiguous.
